# How to convert String into two dimensional array

Tags: groovy

How can I convert a string like this

```
'[["dfd","ewer","errr","ggg"],["yyy","ttt","rrr","ggg"]]'
```

into a list?

I don't want to use `GroovyShell().evaluate()`

Thanks

Comment: That's not a String, that's a list.  Can you explain your problem better? You want to convert a List of Lists of Strings into a list?

Comment: Oh, you mean you have the String `'[["dfd","ewer","errr","ggg"],["yyy","ttt","rrr","ggg"]]'` and you want it split into the lists that represents?

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Actually this is a String passed from JSON
I used  JSON.parse(params.mylist) resolved this

Comment: Maybe this sort of important information should be in the question next time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Eval.me` like so:

```
String input = '[["dfd","ewer","errr","ggg"],["yyy","ttt","rrr","ggg"]]'

List output = Eval.me( input )

assert output.size() == 2
assert output*.size() == [ 4, 4 ]
```

(though of course, [under the covers](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/util/Eval.java#L64), Groovy just calls `GroovyShell.evaluate()`)

Then for pure Groovy, there's `JsonParser`:

```
output = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText( input )
```